# How to use Elastic IP for AWS ECS private servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have an application with private servers on AWS ECS cluster. But, In order to work the application, I need to whitelist the server IPs because I'm using a paid service. All my servers have public IP attached to it. Right now I'm whitelisting all my public IPs for getting the service.

But if I scaled in and then scaled out, all my public IPs will change and all my whitelisted permissions will go. Are there ways to use Elastic IPs to ECS clusters?

Or Is there any other ways to figure this thing out? As all internet traffic is going through the NAT instance for private instances, is there any change that by whitelisting the NAT instance IP will solve the issue? I don't think so, but correct me if I'm wrong.

I have some limitations in trying out all the possibilities on the server because the AWS account is not mine. So, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All instances should be in a private subnet. Your VPC should have a NAT Gateway attached to it. Set the route table to route outbound traffic via the NAT gateway. Now assign the NAT gateway a public IP. Now all requests will come from the NAT gateway with the single public IP.

Comment: All the servers are in private subnet and have a NAT instance attached to it. And also all the outbound traffic from private subnets are routing through the NAT instance. So If I whitelisted the NAT instance IP, will it resolve the issue?

Comment: Should be... Thats the whole point of the NAT gateway; give them access to the internet and no need to assign public IP’s to each instance for outbound traffic.